# if statement with nested functions will not execute

Tags: c, if-statement, strcmp

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
   char      name[30];
   int       age;

   printf("Please enter your name: ");
   scanf("%s", name);

   printf("How old are you %s: ", name);
   scanf("%d", age);

   if (strcmp(name, "Abs") == 1 && age == 25)
      printf("You are the CHOSEN one!\n");
   else
      printf("You are a wankstain!\n");

   fflush(stdin);
   getchar();
}
```

***The if statement seems to ignore the right answer, i have also tried to put the age in brackets to no avail.***

Comment: You better learn debugging your code. It's easier and faster than posting a poor question on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Btw. the chosen one has always been Neo, not Abs.

Comment: i only learned to code last week, i have no one to ask and this is the only place i know of, plus i have compiled it in  my IDE without any errors

Comment: Just Google strcmp, pick one of the first several pages returned, and look at what they say about the return value of strcmp. You are using it wrong.

Comment: `0` would be the correct return value of `strcmp` if the strings are "equal"

Comment: `scanf("%d", age);` change to `scanf("%d", &age);`

Comment: You at least shall tell us what the expect behaviour should be ...

Comment: Flusing `stdin` provokes undefined behaviour (ar least on Linux).

Answer (score 1):

1. Why not read the manual page for `strcmp`. You been to check for zero.
2. Ditto for `scanf` - it does return a value that needs to be checked.
3. Use braces - prevents problems in the future.
4. You do not need to flush `stdin`.

(see http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcmp and http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf)

Comment: I'd however recommend: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcmp.3.html and  http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html as maintained and spam-free.